# Operating System on SSD but can't access files on HDD

Tags: windows-7, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't delete files on Windows 7 (permission)](https://superuser.com/questions/60700/cant-delete-files-on-windows-7-permission)

Just upgraded from Windows XP to Windows 7 and added a SSD. The Windows 7 & Office is in the SSD.
I can see the HDD and my old files but everytime I try to access them e.g., word files, 
It says I'm not authorised to.
I did not delete Windows  XP from the HDD ( dont know how to ).
Can someone help me out please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take ownership of the files & then reset the ACLs.

Open the command prompt, type:

```
<your hdd drive letter>:
takeown /r /dY
icacls * /reset /c /q /t
```

Answer (score 1):

When you open Microsoft Word, try opening it with Right Click and Run As Administrator. When Microsoft Word starts up, try and open the document using File->Open.

If that works, you can right click on the Microsoft Word shortcut, go to the Compatibility tab and check Run As Administrator in order to run it every time without right clicking.

Hope that helps.

(Also, you can right click on your files or folders, go to the Security tab and check which users have Full Control, Press Edit to edit the users and add yourself with full control if you are not in there)

Comment: Thk U 10ft & Sathya for your replies :)