# Can't delete some directories as Admin

Tags: windows-7, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get permissions to delete files on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/60700/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-delete-files-on-windows-7)

I am unable to delete the following directory in Windows 7

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\iTunes
```

The error message that is displayed when I try is:

```
You need permission to perform this action.   
You require permission from the computer's administrator 
to make changes to this folder."
```

I am an Administrator and have UAC set to "Never Notify". iTunes is not running either (it's been uninstalled).

I have tried running `cmd.exe` using "Run as administrator" from the right click context menu, then executing

```
rmdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\iTunes"
```

but it just returns "**Access is denied**."

Any ideas why I can't delete this dir?

Comment: You mention two different folders: ...\programs and ...\programs\itunes, which is it? Windows Explorer definitely has ...\programs open and removing that directory would probably destroy your Start Menu.

Comment: @kreemoweet - sorry, should have been "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\iTunes"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely reason is that someone has the directory (or a file in the directory) open as a handle. You can't delete filesystem objects until the handle is released.

Try looking at Sysinternal's handle-view in Process Explorer (Menu > Find > Handle or DLL).

You've probably got ITunes running as a service with a handle to that folder open. You'll need to kill the process in order to delete the file/folder.

Comment: Yep, turns out I had a different process running with a handle to that dir - launchy.exe. Once killed I could delete the dir. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. I'd vote up if I had more rep. Sorry.

Comment: Process Explorer does not exist in Windows 11.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try to change the owner of the folder to Administrator. http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-take-ownership-of-a-folderfile-in-windows-7/