# Editing Windows system files in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, permissions, system-file

My user works on a piece of software that requires me to edit the **Config.nt** file in the windows directory to work.

Now I navigated to the file location and tried to edit the file by opening with Notepad (as you would any .bat file). I edited it all well and good albeit with a little concern as to how empty the config .sys file was. (it consisted of only one small line which happened to be the one I needed to edit) when I went to save it I got Access Denied. at this point I was logged in as local administrator of the computer. I then tried logging in as the network admin, my own network admin account, and even tried to create a new administrator to see if I could start the permissions from scratch.

I then tried to right click on the windows file and opened properties to change the security. It allowed me to click Edit but did not allow me to add or delete a user and all the tick boxes are greyed out... is there any way I can gain full control of the windows file/ directory in Windows 8? it seems pretty much impossible.

**[Update]**

I have tried the Command lines suggested in the linked question and none of these work I still get permission denied or that the changes couldn't be made even with elevated cmd. will deactivating UAC make any difference?

Comment: And what changes would be required? This file is no longer used and only remains for (whatever) compatibility reasons.

Comment: the line is "Pages=40" I need to change it to "pages=50" its such a simple change that's the annoying thing!

Comment: There’s no such thing as a `Pages` directive...? Anyway: If the program has DOS requirements, you should use a DOS emulator. Because Windows NT does not have DOS, at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get permissions to delete files on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/60700/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-delete-files-on-windows-7)

Comment: I know you're not deleting files, it's the answer that count as a duplicate (i.e. taking ownership/changing permissions). Did you try to use said commands from the [recovery environment](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-8-recovery-environment-command-prompt/)?

Comment: Sorry I meant "Files=40" not "Pages=40" I don't know where that came from

Comment: @and31415 I have tried the elevated command prompt and advanced start up to grant me access as it  says but it still does not work saying that it could not be processed and or access denied

Comment: @NathanTaylor: Daniel B. has the correct answer: `Files=40` is a workaround for an MS-DOS problem, so only MS-DOS programs need it'. Since Windows 7 can't run MS-DOS programs, the whole point is moot.

Comment: @MSalters Well that cant be right considering I have the program up and running on a windows 7 machine ive had it running on XP and 98 too

Comment: @NathanTaylor: IOW, you don't know exactly **what** you have, but it's not a DOS program.

Comment: @MSalters No I know Exactly what program it is its called StockPro and im sure it is a DOS program because in the setup process I change the Config.sys file as stated above. It runs with a batch file and that's all I know.

Comment: I can Confirm that it **is** a DOS program and we have it running on the Windows 7 machine by Editing the Config.sys file in the Windows registry. the problem with windows 8 is that I cant even move files and folders into the Windows Directory... how can I combat this??

Comment: @NathanTaylor: While Windows NT/XP (and later) do not run DOS programs, they do run batch scripts. The program is probably a Windows 95/98 program (which _did_ have a config.sys, but even there it shouldn't matter).

Comment: @MSalters That may be why it is working on the windows 7 machine but for this software if the Files=40 then a message pops up in the "DOS" screen saying that the files need to be changed to 50 then you can only cancel the startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the icacls and Takeown to work in elevated command prompt and this helped me to take ownership and gain full control rights to the File. what I wasn't aware of was that there were two different Config.nt files one in the root of System32 and another in one of the folders in WinSxS. I happened to give myself control to the wrong config file. I corrected this, changed the Files=40 to Files=50 and it worked fine. StockPro is now fully operational.

Answer (score 2):

UAC prevents users with administrator privileges to change system files when you open them through Explorer. I am not sure about Windows 8, but in Windows 7 you could start Notepad with the 'Run as administrator' option, open the file from notepad, edit and save it.

Comment: It doesn't even allow me to save in the directory when I navigate there in the save box in Notepad there aren't any files visible and it says I don't have the permission to save in the location

Comment: And you did make sure to use the 'run as administrator' option when starting Notepad?

Comment: yes I tried and the same message appeared