# Why does Windows say I need permission to delete files

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I'm logged in as an admin on my Windows 10 machine. When I go to delete a folder, it says I need permission. I set the permission on all files in the folder and its subfolders so that anyone can delete the folder, yet this didn't help. I also notice that the folder is read-only. I remove the read-only from it and its subfolders, but it still does not delete the folder and files in the folder still exist. Only if I manually start deleting files one by one am I able to delete the folder.

Why is this happening?
If I'm an admin and have set full permission on the files and folders, why is it telling me I need permission?

Comment: Who is the owner of a folder?

Comment: How do I see who the owner is?

Comment: Right-click > Properties

Comment: There's nothing under Properties that indicate an owner. Under Properties you can select Security and set the permissions, but I already mentioned that I did that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get permissions to delete files on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/60700/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-delete-files-on-windows-7)

Comment: @BigStar I know it's more of a side thing but FYI if you want to find the owner of a file/folder you go Properties -> Security -> Advanced Settings

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the parent folder was read-only. Even though I was deleting only the sub folders within the parent folder, Windows refused to delete all of them if the parent folder had the read-only attribute set. By removing the read-only property on the parent folder was I able to delete all the sub folders.

Comment: Some folders such as C drive like this. Usually I add the Everyone permission and Full Control under Security option. Then I could delete it.