# Windows 10 - .pdf icon cannot be removed from the desktop

Tags: windows-10, desktop-icons

From a web page I saved as a .pdf, now I have the icon on the desktop.

But,I cannot remove it,open or rename this icon.

I tried to move it to the recycle bin but nothing happens.

Can,please,someone help me.

Thank you

Comment: Sometimes the icon is deleted but the desktop is not refreshed. Try F5 to refresh.

Comment: KK. what happens when you try to remove/rename/open it? What is the error...?
Have you tried refreshing and restarting the PC?

Comment: @harrymc,I tried many times to refresh with F5,nothing happens.@DxTx,when I try to remove/rename/open nothing happens and I don't have errors.I tried refreshing and restarting but nothing happens,the icon is always there.

Answer (score 0):

In all versions of Windows, the Desktop folder contents are stored in two locations.
Windows shows the contents of both folders in a single view.

- The "Common Desktop" for all users is located in `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`
- The user desktop in his profile at `%userprofile%\Desktop`.

If this desktop icon has become corrupted, I suggest:

- Preventive: Run `chkdsk` of the disk.
  If any errors are found, more information is available via the
  [Event Viewer Log](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/40822-read-chkdsk-log-event-viewer-windows-10-a.html).
  If errors are found, you may fix them with `chkdsk /f`, but
  ensure you have good backups before starting.
- Preventive: Run
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
  to check the integrity of Windows.
- Deletion: Locate the problematic icon in one of the above folders and try to
  delete it using Explorer.
  If an error occurs, let us know. You might need to
  [take ownership to delete the icon](https://superuser.com/questions/60700/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-delete-files-on-windows-7),
  but only of the icon - do not change the properties of the folder itself.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91663/discussion-on-answer-by-harrymc-windows-10-pdf-icon-cannot-be-removed-from-th).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem,that was filename too long.

With 7zip:

- I searched for the file that I could not delete
- with 7zip, I can rename the file and shorten it
- then, I deleted it