# How to delete read-only file from USB?

Tags: read-only

I have a memory card which i received from an institute. Even though it is not read-only its files are, so I cannot delete or copy something to the memory card. I have tried diskpart clean and it returns the error "DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)."

Answer (score 0):

Cyclic redundancy error means a bad sector on the card.

The card has most probably gone bad, so ask for a replacement.

If any important data needs salvage, see the following article for free products:
[Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm).

Comment: been there, done that

Comment: In that case the card is dead.

Comment: I am able to use the file that are on the SD card, what i can't do is delete them or copy new things

Comment: This might be a simpler case, where you just don't have full permissions on these files. In this case the card is good. For gaining ownership and permissions see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/60704/8672) that uses batch commands, but you may do the same [from Explorer](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-take-ownership-files-and-folders-windows-10).

Comment: It's not showing the security option when i click on properties, there's only  General, Customize, and Sharing and when using takeown command it's displaying"File ownership cannot be applied on insecure file systems; there's no support for ACLs

Comment: The card is then formatted as FAT32 or similar that has no permissions. The last possibilities are damage that affects these operations or a hardware lock that prevents any modification. For the last option, search for any switch on the card itself. If you can find nothing, I recommend giving up on the card.